# Access data from ADLS using Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to access data files stored in ADLS location via Azure Databricks using storage account access keys.
To access data files, I am using python notebook in azure databricks and below command works fine,

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
  "<access-key>"
)
```

However, when I try to list the directory using below command, it throws an error

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net")
```

ERROR:

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.ls.
: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, GET, https://<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container-name>?upn=false&resource=filesystem&maxResults=500&timeout=90&recursive=false, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:<request-id> Time:2021-08-03T08:53:28.0215432Z"
```

I am not sure on what permission would it require and how can I proceed with it.

Also, I am using ADLS Gen2 and Azure Databricks(Trial - premium).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the "Blob Contributor" or "Read Blob Contributor" permission for this storage account?

Comment: Yes, I have contributor access on the storage account.

Comment: You need `Blob Contributor`, simple `Contributor` won't work

Comment: Okay, I don't have `Blob Contributor` access to myself and neither can I provide it to me. I will check on getting the access. Thanks :)

Comment: also, `abfss` protocol won't work with storage key - you need service principal for it

Comment: Got it, I have also tried `Credential Passthrough` as well, will that also not work in my scenario ?

Comment: Credential passthrough should work, but you still need to have `Blob contributor` permission

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) , Will try to get `Blob Container` access and check again.

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt, I got `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role and then I was able to access azure storage via Databricks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The complete config key is called "spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.adlsiqdigital.dfs.core.windows.net"

However it would be beneficial for a production environment to use a service account and a mount point. This way the actions on the storage can be traced back to this application more easily than just with the generic access key and the mount point avoid specifying the connection string everywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Yes, we would be using mount points for production environment. I was testing this out on temporary basis and hence used access keys. I have also tried using the complete config key as suggested but it gives the same error.

Comment: You could try specifying the config directly in the cluster and not in code.

Comment: I have added the configuration in the cluster as,
`spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net true`
but still getting the same error, `This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.`

Comment: Tried adding below in the spark config but still seeing the same error,
`spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net <access-key>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net","<your-storage-account-access-key>")
dbutils.fs.mount(source = "abfss://<container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/", mount_point = "/mnt/test")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried implementing this but still getting the same error.
`Operation failed: &#34;This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.&#34;, 403, HEAD, https://<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container-name>/?upn=false&amp;action=getAccessControl&amp;timeout=90`

Answer (score 0):

You can mount ADLS storage account using access key via Databricks and then read/write data. Please try below code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})

dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/<mount-name>")
```